# Controlling the max thread count of SelectMany

Tags: c#, system.reactive, reactiveui

Is there a method I can use to set the maximum thread count of an IObservable.SelectMany?

The following code works great for updating the UI as items are processed, but the task I'm trying to execute is a bit of a resource hog at the moment. I would like to set the max threads to like two, to be a bit lighter on resource usage.

```
AsyncCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncObservable(_ => 
{
    // Set progress bar indicator to 0

    var set = new [] {...} // The set of items to process

    // Set the progress bar indicator max to the count of the items to process

    return set
        .ToObservable()
        .SelectMany((item, index) => Task.Run(() =>
        {
            // Process item

            return item;
        }), (item, index, processed) => item); 
});

AsyncCommand
    .ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler)
    .Subscribe(item => 
    {
        // Step the progress bar indicator
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Merge` has a max parallelism parameter:

```
AsyncCommand = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncObservable(_ => 
{
    // Set progress bar indicator to 0

    var set = new [] {...} // The set of items to process

    // Set the progress bar indicator max to the count of the items to process

    return set
        .ToObservable()
        .Select(item => Observable.FromAsync(() => DoAsyncProcess(item))))
        .Merge(2);
});
```

See also a [more advanced solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30955097/reactive-pipeline-how-to-control-parallelism/30961985#30961985)

Answer (score 0):

`SelectMany`, as used in your code snippet, does not introduce any concurrency by itself and therefore does not create any thread. It's the TPL that does (since you use `Task.Run`). The TPL usually does a good job at not creating too many threads to get the job done. Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11075320/using-tpl-how-do-i-set-a-max-threadpool-size) and subsequently [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee789351) if you really want to throttle the maximum number of threads.

As a simple alternative, use an AsyncSemaphore from Stephen Cleary's great [AsyncEx](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Nito.AsyncEx) package and put your processing code between `WaitAsync` and `Release` calls.